# Display Same bar buttons throughout application

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to display the navigation bar with 4 buttons on it.
The buttons need to stay there throughout the app. but it must be able to navigate.

In short I need the same bar for both parent and its child viewcontroller.
How can this be achieved?

I **DONT** want to repeat the buttons code in all the viewcontroller. It is for sure possible. I have seen this in many app.
But any idea towards the path will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4];
```

put the above sample code in Application delegate class.